# React Add opacity to first and last items in visible area of div items while scrolling

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a Div which contains list of div items.
While a user is scrolling I want the Opacity to be applied to based on below conditions

When scrolling up, opacity should be applied to below visible item in container and upper item opacity should be removed

When scrolling down, opacity should be applied to top visible item in container and bottom opacity for item should be removed

```
 class HelloWorld extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      items:[]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount (){
    this.setState({
      items: ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8", "Item 9", "Item 10", "Item 11", "Item 12"]
    })
  }


  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="mainContainer">
          <div className="childContainer"> 
        {this.state.items.map((match, key) => (
                 <div> {match}</div>
                ))}
            </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

$blue: #a3d5d3;

body {
  background-color: $blue;
}



.mainContainer {
        height: 80px;
        width: 320px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 26px;
        position: relative;
    }


.childContainer {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}


    .mainContainer::before {
        content: '';
        position: fixed;
        width: 300px;
        height: 25px;
        //background: linear-gradient(white, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.001)); 
       background: linear-gradient(180deg, red 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    }

    .mainContainer::after {
        content: '';
        position: fixed;
        width: 300px;
        height: 25px;
        // background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.001), white);
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, red 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    }
```

ReactDOM.render(, document.getElementById('root'));

How could I achieve this with css or handling events in React ?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have updated what I have tried.

Comment: Sounds like a job for the [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Comment: You need JS for this, you can't do this with CSS only. There isn't any JS you tried?

Comment: No I haven't tried I need to do this in React